# how to count the number off facebook comments in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, comments

i am designing a blog in rails and i have successfully integrated facbook comment in it my code is as follows:

in the application.html.erb i added this

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=202813259861933";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and in the my post i.e show.html.erb i added this

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%= post_path %>" data-width="290" data-num-posts="20"></div>
```

which is working very fine 
**the problem is when i try to count the number of comment for a particular post**,with the facebook comment count code, it outputs nothing. could anyone help get around this cos it seems this code is not working for rails application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code maybe?

```
   <script>(function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>

<a expr:href='data:post.url + "#fb-root"'><fb:comments-count    expr:href='data:post.canonicalUrl'></fb:comments-count> comments</a>-count> comments</a>
```